# How can I pass a Boolean value to a placeholder while using benchmark_model in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, benchmarking

My first two layers of my model are :

```
('#', 1, '#', '|Input Tensors {}|:', (<tf.Tensor 'import/Placeholder:0' shape=(5, 360, 480, 3) dtype=float32>,))
('#', 2, '#', '|Input Tensors {}|:', (<tf.Tensor 'import/phase_train:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=bool>,))
```

I want to benchmark the model using Tensorflow's benchmark tool. I have to set two parameters (a float and a bool).

i am using benchmark tool like this :

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model \
--graph=saved_model_fp32.pb \
--input_layer='Placeholder','phase_train' \
--input_layer_shape='5,360,480,3:0' \
--input_layer_type='float','bool' \
--output_layer='conv_decode1/cond/Merge' \
--show_run_order=false --show_time=false \
--show_memory=false --show_summary=false \
--show_flops=true #--logtostderr
```

but it complains about the way i am passing the boolean value :

```
2018-09-14 13:37:33.529605: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-09-14 13:37:33.561214: I tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model.cc:492] Initialized session in 0.031689s
2018-09-14 13:37:33.561269: I tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model.cc:323] Running benchmark for max 1 iterations, max -1 seconds without detailed stat logging, with -1s sleep between inferences
2018-09-14 13:37:33.979259: E tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model.cc:302] Error during inference: Invalid argument: The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [0]
     [[Node: conv1/cond/Switch = Switch[T=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_phase_train_0_1, _arg_phase_train_0_1)]]
2018-09-14 13:37:33.979956: I tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model.cc:344] Failed on run 0
2018-09-14 13:37:33.979975: E tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model.cc:562] Timing failed with Invalid argument: The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [0]
     [[Node: conv1/cond/Switch = Switch[T=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_phase_train_0_1, _arg_phase_train_0_1)]]
```

How should I use the benchmark tool properly?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the straight-forward way is to define a constant tensor with the same name `tf.constant(False, dtype=bool, shape=[], name='phase_train')` and set it in place of the `phase_train` placeholder.

That worked for me :)